# Solving nonlinear 1D advection pde with MoC

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, characteristics

I would like to solve the 1D nonlinear advection equation with the method of characteristics. Here is my notation:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\rho_t + (1+\rho)\rho_x = 0\\
\rho = \rho(x,t); \quad \rho(x,0) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
What I have been up to is the following, using the parameter s:
\begin{align}
&\frac{d\rho}{dt} = \frac{dx}{ds}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + \frac{dt}{ds}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0\\
\Longrightarrow \; & \frac{dt}{ds} = 1 ;\quad  t(0)=0 \; \Longrightarrow \; t=s \\
\Longrightarrow \; & \frac{d\rho}{ds} = 0 ;\quad \rho(0)=\rho_0 \; \Longrightarrow \; \rho = \rho_0 \\
\Longrightarrow \; & \frac{dx}{ds}=1+\rho= 1+\rho_0 ;\quad x(0) = f(\rho_0) \; \Longrightarrow \; x = (1+\rho_0)s + f(\rho_0)
\end{align}
So that I end up with
\begin{equation}
    f(\rho) = x - (1+\rho)t \; \Longrightarrow \; \rho = F(x - [1+\rho]t )
\end{equation}
I tried to apply several techniques I found to find the solution of the above Riemann problem using the method of characteristics. I have the general form of the solution as F but I would like to have the analytic solution for this case so I can plot for several times and see the shockwave.

Note: This problem comes from [this online document](https://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2011/Spring/physics221a/LECTURES/CH11_SHOCKS.pdf), chapter 11.

Comment: You must provide a condition on the "inflow" boundary, for instance $\rho(0,t)=1$. If you just want to visualize the solution I can provide two lines of Wolfram code that will do the trick.

Comment: I think you haven't used the initial condition on $\rho$ yet, which yields $\rho_0 = \frac{1}{1+f(\rho_0)^2}$?

Comment: As J.Jacquelin did below, using the unitial condition on $\rho$ leads to a cubic equation that I have no idea how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculus is correct. You found the general solution :
$$\rho=F\left(x-(1+\rho)t\right)$$
Condition :
$$\rho(x,0)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}=F\left(x-(1+\rho)0\right)=F\left(x\right)$$
The function $F$ is determined :
$$F(X)=\frac{1}{1+X^2}$$
We put this function into the general solution where $X=x-(1+\rho)t$
$$\rho=\frac{1}{1+(x-(1+\rho)t)^2}$$
This is the solution on implicit form.

In order to obtain the explicit solution, solve the cubic equation for $\rho$ :
$$(1+(x-(1+\rho)t)^2)\rho-1=0$$

ADITION after the discussion in comments.

There is no difficulty to plot the figures that you saw in the document :
https://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2011/Spring/physics221a/LECTURES/CH11_SHOCKS.pdf

For exemple, to plot the curves corresponding tu figure 11.1 :
$$x=(1+\rho)t\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{\rho}-1}$$
Plot the two branches with signs $+$ and $-$.

[image]

Inverse the axis if you want it in the standard position.

Comment: Thamks for answering. I actually came to the same conclusion a few minutes ago. My next problem is when I'm computing the $\delta = b^2 - 4ac$ of this equation, which sign is undetermined because, well, in (x,t) parameters are supposed to be both varying parameters and though $\delta$ is not a scalar but a space of solutions.

Comment: Apologies, I had a slightly different in mind indeed.. Still you are right, the formula cannot be written explicitly. 
Why I would like to have a explicit formula is to plot the solution for several time step to compare with what is shown in the book I mentionned. 
Another contributor kindly proposed a Wolfram code to do that but I wanted to do it on gnuplot or python. You know, the old way..

Comment: There is no need for an explicit formula to plot $\rho(x,t)$ as a function of $t$ for given $x$. Compute the formula of $t$ as a function of $\rho$ which is an explicit equation. Plot $t$ as a function of $\rho$ with $t$ on horizontal axis and $\rho$ on vertical axis.

Comment: If I rewrite the equation as 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\rho}-1=[x−(1+ρ)t]^2
\end{equation}
Then I cannot isolate t from ρ because of the square

Comment: Here the advection velocity depends on $\rho$ itself, which is the problem when I look for an explicit analytic solution. Perhaps I should quit looking for a beautiful formula, but do you have an idea of how they did in fig. 11 of the book to plot the solution ?

Comment: $$t=\frac{x-\sqrt{\frac{1}{\rho}-1}}{1+\rho}$$

Comment: @Dash. I cannot understand why you don't know how to plot the figures corresponding to those of the book. It is very easy. For example, see the addition to my main answer.